# What should we call our chat room? [Redux]

Tags: discussion, chat

Our chat room is currently named "The Ban Hammer", which makes sense for a site called Moderators.  But our name has caught up to our scope (thanks Pops!) and this chat-room name doesn't fit as well with Community Building.  Building includes inviting people in, not banning or hammering them.

So what should we call our chat room now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Town Hall

(where members of communities come together... this line here to provide 30 characters)

Comment: At the time the name was changed this and "Community Center" were tied and one of the mods flipped a coin.  I'm marking this accepted to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

I like [the imagery associated with community centers](https://www.google.com/search?q=community+center&tbm=isch). They are central areas where people get together to engage in many of the casual aspects of community building. Seems to fit with the idea of a chat room; it could be named **Community Center**.

Not very exciting, but it's relatively unambiguous and I think that's very desirable at this stage in our development.

If we want something more exciting, we could go with the time-honored tradition of naming gathering places after people:

**Maude R. Ayters Memorial Community Center**

Comment: "Community Center" sounds reasonable to me.  I've no idea who Maude R. Ayters is and Google's not helping, so... not that.

Comment: Say it five times fast.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Hmm.

Comment: "Memorial"? Poor Maude.

Comment: "Memorial" sounds like a little too grave of a name (no pun intended) and I don't think many people would get the joke. I *do* like "Community Center" though

Answer (score 2):

The Open Door

Answer (score 1):

The Welcome Mat

Answer (score 1):

The Roundtable